# Restriction of a smooth function of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm trying to show in the context of manifold that a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ when restricted to $f|_{S^1}: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ it's also smooth. ($S^1= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x²+y²=1 \}$)

Let $p=(x,y) \in S^1$ be and $(U, \phi)$ a chart such that $p\in U$. I have to show that $f|_{S^1} \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U) \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth in $\phi(p)$.

$(f|_{S^1} \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(p)) = f(p)$.

As I can conclude that this is smooth, I have difficulty with the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left.f\right\rvert_{S^1}\circ \phi^{-1}=f\circ \phi^{-1}$ as functions, and therefore (since $\phi(U)$ is open in $\Bbb R^1$) this is just composition of smooth functions $[\text{open subset of }\Bbb R]\to\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ in the usual, mundane sense.

Answer (score 2):

General fact: if $M$ is a smooth manifold, $N\subseteq M$ is a submanifold, and $f:M\to \Bbb R$ is smooth, then $f|_N:N\to \Bbb R$ is also smooth. Because it is the composition $f\circ \iota$, where the inclusion $\iota:N\to M$ is smooth as well.